# Creating a custom jquery selector (not filter/pseudo selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I wanted to create a custom selector similar to [Basic CSS Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/), not like those Pseudo selectors which starts with a colon (created using `$.expr[':']`). 
This is to incorporate the [`document.elementFromPoint`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint) method to jquery.

I wrote a code for that as follows:

```
$._find = $.find;
$.find = function(query, context, extra, seed ){
    var start,end,expr,_ref,top,left;
    if(typeof query === 'string'){
        start = query.indexOf("(");
        end = query.indexOf(")",start);
        if(start !== -1 && end !== -1){
            expr = "["+query.slice(start+1,end)+"]";
            _ref = $.parseJSON(expr);top=_ref[0];left=_ref[1];
            console.log(document.elementFromPoint(top,left));
            return $([document.elementFromPoint(top,left)]);
        }
    }
    return $._find.apply(null,[query, context, extra, seed]);
};
```

It works for the normal queries. but when a code `$('(10,20)')` is executed, an empty jquery result is returned.
The problem is happening at the line `return $([document.elementFromPoint(top,left)]);` as the previous line happens to give a valid DOM Element.
Any comment is welcome.

PS: I'm not looking for a Pseudo-Selector,Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with just returning the DOM Element then?  You can always wrap it with a jQuery selector later if you want to use it that way.  Alternatively, get rid of the square brackets and just `return $(document.elementFromPoint(top,left))`

Comment: @Archer i tried it, and it will not work, the fix is like this, `return $.makeArray(document.elementFromPoint(top,left), extra)`, any way this will work only for one selector, and will break the queries like `$('(10,20),div')...`.